# Synchronizing audio file directories of different types

Tags: linux, windows, audio-conversion

My music library is encoded as .flac files. I have a backup in .ogg format for carrying around. It's simple enough to just convert the whole tree of flacs to ogg, including the path structure.

**Here's what I want to do:**

When I add new music to my main .flac directory, I want it to recognize files that are not yet converted to .ogg and then convert them automatically.

So I have my Flac directory and my Ogg directory. `IF` there is a filename (minus the extension) in the Flac directory that has no .ogg equivalent, then convert the file and put it in the appropriate place for the tree.
Ideas?